# Get the number of the records without duplicating

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the number of stop_name in the behaviour table without duplicating records but I am getting this error below:

So if I have 1 records with the stop_name `alex alley` and 3 records with the stop_name `John alley` I want to get the result `2`.
How can I fix it?

**Query:**

```
select stop_name DISTINCT
     , count(*) as totalCount
FROM behaviour
where mac = '10:A5:D0:06:C6:E9'
```

But I am getting the error:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT, count(*) as totalCount FROM behaviour where mac = '10:A5:D0:06:C6:E9'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select count(distinct stop_name) as totalCount
from behaviour
where mac = '10:A5:D0:06:C6:E9'
```